# Scrapy cannot download picture to local

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

I am using [Scrapy (0.22)](http://scrapy.org/) to crawl one site. I need to do three things:

1. I need the category and subcategory of the images
2. I need download the images and store them at local
3. I need store the categroy,subcategory,image url in Mongo

But now I am blocked,I use 'pipelines' to download the image, but my code can not work, it cannot download the picture to local.

Also, since I want to store the information in Mongo, anyone can give me some suggest on the "Mongo table structure"?

My code is as following:

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'tutorial.pipelines.TutorialPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = '/ttt'
```

**items.py**

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

    class TutorialItem(Item):
        # define the fields for your item here like:
        # name = Field()
        catname=Field()
        caturl=Field()
        image_urls = Field()
        images = Field()
        pass
```

**pipelines.py**

```
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from pprint import pprint as pp

class TutorialPipeline(object):
    # def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    #     for image_url in item['image_urls']:
    #         yield Request(image_url)

    # def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # print '**********************===================*******************'
        # return item
        # pp(item)
        # pass

    def get_media_requests(self,item,info):
        # pass
        pp('**********************===================*******************')

        # yield Request(item['image_urls'])
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            # pass
            # print image_url
            yield Request(image_url)
```

**spider.py**

```
import scrapy
import os
from pprint import pprint as pp
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spider import Spider

from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from tutorial.items import TutorialItem
from pprint import pprint as pp

class BaiduSpider(scrapy.spider.Spider):
    name='baidu'
    start_urls=[
        # 'http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/'
        'http://giphy.com/categories'
    ]

    domain='http://giphy.com'

    def parse(self,response):
        selector=Selector(response)

        topCategorys=selector.xpath('//div[@id="None-list"]/a')

        # pp(topCategorys)
        items=[]
        for tc in topCategorys:
            item=TutorialItem()
            item['catname']=tc.xpath('./text()').extract()[0]
            item['caturl']=tc.xpath('./@href').extract()[0]
            if item['catname']==u'ALL':
                continue
            reqUrl=self.domain+'/'+item['caturl']
            # pp(reqUrl)
            yield Request(url=reqUrl,meta={'caturl':reqUrl},callback=self.getSecondCategory)
    def getSecondCategory(self,response):
        selector=Selector(response)
        # pp(response.meta['caturl'])
        # pp('*****************=================**************')

        secondCategorys=selector.xpath('//div[@class="grid_9 omega featured-category-tags"]/div/a')

        # pp(secondCategorys)
        items=[]
        for sc in secondCategorys:
            item=TutorialItem()
            item['catname']=sc.xpath('./div/h4/text()').extract()[0]
            item['caturl']=sc.xpath('./@href').extract()[0]
            items.append(item)

            reqUrl=self.domain+item['caturl']
        # pp(items)
            # pp(item)
            # pp(reqUrl)
            yield Request(url=reqUrl,meta={'caturl':reqUrl},callback=self.getImages)

    def getImages(self,response):
        selector=Selector(response)
        # pp(response.meta['caturl'])
        # pp('*****************=================**************')


        # images=selector.xpath('//ul[@class="gifs  freeform grid_12"]/div[position()=3]')
        images=selector.xpath('//*[contains (@class,"hoverable-gif")]')
        # images=selector.xpath('//ul[@class="gifs  freeform grid_12"]//div[@class="hoverable-gif"]')
        # pp(len(images))
        items=[]
        for image in images:
            item=TutorialItem()
            item['image_urls']=image.xpath('./a/figure/img/@src').extract()[0]
            # item['imgName']=image.xpath('./a/figure/img/@alt').extract()[0]
            items.append(item)
            # pp(item)
            # pp(items)
            # pp('==============************==============')

        # pp(items)
        # items=[{'images':"hello world"}]
        return items
```

Addition,there are not errors in the output,just is as following:

```
2014-12-21 13:49:56+0800 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: TutorialPipeline
2014-12-21 13:49:56+0800 [baidu] INFO: Spider opened
2014-12-21 13:49:56+0800 [baidu] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-12-21 13:49:56+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2014-12-21 13:49:56+0800 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2014-12-21 13:50:07+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com/categories> (referer: None)
2014-12-21 13:50:08+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/science/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:08+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/sports/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:08+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/news-politics/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:09+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/transportation/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:09+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/interests/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:09+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/memes/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:09+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/tv/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:09+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/gaming/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:10+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/nature/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:10+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/emotions/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:10+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/movies/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:10+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/holiday/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:11+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/reactions/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:11+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/music/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:11+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com//categories/decades/> (referer: http://giphy.com/categories)
2014-12-21 13:50:12+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://giphy.com/search/the-colbert-report/> (referer: http://giphy.com//categories/news-politics/)
2014-12-21 13:50:12+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://giphy.com/search/the-colbert-report/>
    {'image_urls': u'http://media1.giphy.com/media/2BDLDXFaEiuBy/200_s.gif'}
2014-12-21 13:50:12+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://giphy.com/search/the-colbert-report/>
    {'image_urls': u'http://media2.giphy.com/media/WisjAI5QGgsrC/200_s.gif'}
2014-12-21 13:50:12+0800 [baidu] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://giphy.com/search/the-colbert-report/>
    {'image_urls': u'http://media3.giphy.com/media/ZgDGEMihlZXCo/200_s.gif'}
.............
```

Comment: Please provide the errors/results you are getting. It will help answerers triage your code better.

Comment: @kartikg3 there is no erros,it seems everything is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see it, there is no need for you to override the `ImagesPipeline`, because you are not modifying its behavior. But, since you are doing it, you should do it properly.
When overriding `ImagesPipeline`, two methods should be overriden:

- **get_media_requests(item, info)** should return a `Request` for every URL in `image_urls`. This part you have done correctly.
- **item_completed(results, items, info)** is called when all image requests for a single item have completed (either finished downloading, or failed for some reason). From the [official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.22/topics/images.html#scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline.item_completed):

  > The **item_completed()** method must return the output that will be sent
  >   to subsequent item pipeline stages, so you must return (or drop) the
  >   item, as you would in any pipeline.

So, to make your custom images pipeline work, you need to override the **item_completed()** method, like this:

```
def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
    image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
    if not image_paths:
        raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
    item['image_paths'] = image_paths
    return item
```

Further on, about other issues in your code that make it not work as expected:

1. You are not actually creating any useful items.
   If you take a look at your `parse()` and `getSecondCategory()` functions, you will notice that you are not returning nor yielding any items. Although you seem to have prepared the `items` list, which you obviously wanted to use to store your items, it is never used to actually pass the items further down the processing path. At one point, you just yield a `Request` for the next page, and when the function finishes, your `items` are deleted.
2. You are not using your `caturl` info that you are passing via the `meta` dictionary. You are passing this info both in `parse()`˙and `getSecondCategory()`, but you never collect it in the callback function. Thus it is also being ignored.

So, the only thing that is basically going to work is the images pipeline, if you fix it as I already suggested. In order to fix these issue in your code, follow the guidelines below (please keep in mind that this is not tested, it is just a guideline for your consideration):

```
def parse(self,response):
    selector=Selector(response)
    topCategorys=selector.xpath('//div[@id="None-list"]/a')

    for tc in topCategorys:
        # no need to create the item just yet,
        # only get the category and the url so we can
        # continue the work in our callback
        catname = tc.xpath('./text()').extract()[0]
        caturl = tc.xpath('./@href').extract()[0]
        if catname == u'ALL':
            continue
        reqUrl=self.domain + '/' + caturl

        # pass the category name in the meta so we can retreive it
        # from the response in the callback function
        yield Request(url=reqUrl,meta={'catname': catname},
                      callback=self.getSecondCategory)

def getSecondCategory(self,response):
    selector=Selector(response)
    secondCategorys=selector.xpath('//div[@class="grid_9 omega featured-category-tags"]/div/a')

    # retreive the category name from the response
    # meta dictionary, which was copied from our request
    catname = response.meta['catname']

    for sc in secondCategorys:
        # still no need to create the item, 
        # since we are just trying to get to 
        # the subcategory
        subcatname = sc.xpath('./div/h4/text()').extract()[0]
        subcaturl = sc.xpath('./@href').extract()[0]

        reqUrl=self.domain + '/' + subcaturl

        # this time pass both the category and the subcategory
        # so we can read them both in the callback function
        yield Request(url=reqUrl,meta={'catname':catname, 'subcatname':subcatname},
                        callback=self.getImages)

def getImages(self,response):
    selector=Selector(response)

    # retreive the category and subcategory name
    catname = response.meta['catname']
    subcatname = response.meta['subcatname']

    images = selector.xpath('//*[contains (@class,"hoverable-gif")]')

    for image in images:
        # now could be a good time to create the items
        item=TutorialItem()

        # fill the items category information. You can concatenate
        # the category and subcategory if you like, or you can 
        # add another field in your TutorialItem called subcatname
        item['catname'] = catname + ":" + subcatname
        # or alternatively:
        # item['catname'] = catname
        # item['subcatname'] = subcatname

        item['image_urls']=image.xpath('./a/figure/img/@src').extract()[0]

        # no need to store the items in the list to return
        # it later, we can just yield the items as they are created
        yield item
```